# Need help with gradient descent convergence calculation

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

We are given $\alpha=1-8\eta$, where $\eta$ is the step size. We are also given the following ($z$ is irrelevant, but basically it's the output of the algorithm at step $k$):
[image]

We are asked what values of $\eta$ in the set $\{0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15\}$ make the gradient descent take the most steps before convergence. The answer is $\eta=0.1$ and $\eta=0.15$.

In a previous question, we find out that $\eta=0.125$ causes the gradient to converge in a single step/without oscillating, since according to the information convergence without oscillation happen when $1>\alpha\ge0$, therefore when $\alpha=1=1-8\eta$, $\eta=0.125$.

Therefore, the solution goes, since these two $\eta$ are the furthest from $0.125$, they would make the descent the slowest/takes the most steps.

I do not understand this; if we plug the values from that set into $\alpha=1-8\eta$, we get $$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\alpha & \eta  \\
\hline
0.2 & 0.1  \\
0.12 & 0.11  \\
0.04 & 0.12\\
0 & 0.125\\
-0.04 & 0.13\\
-0.12 & 0.14\\
-0.2 & 0.15 
\end{array}
$$

According to the table, convergence occurs without oscillation when $1>\alpha\ge 0$, so shouldn't it converge immediately when $\eta$ is within $[0.1,0.125]$?

---

Excerpts from the relevant MIT notes have been attached below for reference:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the context of this? What ***is*** $\alpha$? The chart makes it seem like at each iteration of the algorithm, $z^{(k)}$ is multiplied by $\alpha$. How is that a gradient descent algorithm? In gradient descent, there is a gradient computed at each iteration, and a step of some positive size is taken in that direction.

Comment: @Joe Hi, I attached the relevant bits from the MIT notes, which hopefully will provide some context for this question.

Comment: There's nothing like converging in a single step or converging immediately. Even with $\alpha=0$ it takes so many steps. You misunderstood seriously if you thought that at $\alpha$ of $0$ it converges in one step. For $0\le\alpha<1$, it will converge in different number of steps.

Comment: @KayK, actually, if $\alpha=0$, then it does converge to the global optimal solution of $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ in that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have rewritten the problem by changing variables to $z^{(k)}$, so that the global minimum of the function occurs at $z^{(k)}=0$, and each update of gradient descent is just multiplying $z^{(k)}$ by a constant. If that constant is zero, then it converges in one step. If the constant is positive but less than one, it converges without oscillating, but it never "reaches" the global minimum. Your gradient descent algorithm would need some stopping criteria. A typical choice is when the norm of the gradient is below some positive threshold.

In this problem, the gradient is proportional to $z^{(k)}$, in particular $\nabla_x f(x^{(k)}) = 8z^{(k)}$, so a threshold on the gradient is the same as a (different) threshold on the size of $z^{(k)}$.

The smaller the positive constant, the fewer steps the algorithm would take before reaching the threshold.

Of course, "number of steps" is an integer, so for each positive integer, there would be a range of values that all took that number of steps to reach the threshold.